# In predicate logic, is there a word for a term that must be true in all cases for the expression to be true?

Tags: math, logic

Take the following example:

```
A AND (B OR C)
```

Obviously *A* must be true for the expression to be true.

Another example:

```
(A AND (B OR C)) OR (D AND E AND A)
```

Again, *A* has to be true, but appears multiple times, in two different legs of the expression.

Is there a word for a variable/term that *must* be true regardless of how deeply nested it is for the expression as a whole to be true? Something like a dominant node in graph theory.

Comment: There is not any specific name, as `A and` is distributed over `Or` based on a rule in mathematical logic.

Answer (score 0):

There is a converse, an [implicant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Implicant). In that case if the implicant is true, the whole expression must be true.

From a search, it seems the one you want is an **implicate**. See e.g. [http://www.cs.albany.edu/~ritries/KAIS-1819R1.pdf](http://www.cs.albany.edu/%7Eritries/KAIS-1819R1.pdf) or https://arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/1401/1401.3475.pdf. Since you mention "variable/term", an implicate must be a literal (a variable or a negation of a variable) or a disjunction of literals.

But it seems to be even less known than implicant and easily confused with the verb.